# A 2x2 grid in flexbox

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

I made a demo in which I make a 1 by 4 grid; 1 row and 4 columns. It's working fine, but I want it to display a 2 by 2 grid when the user screen is less than `720px`. I tried to use media query like [this](https://jsbin.com/xudihuxato/edit?html,css,output):

```
body, * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: grey;
}


 @media only screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 720px) {
   .box {
       background-color: blue;
   }
 }
```

How can change my layout when screen size is less than 720px?

Bin: https://jsbin.com/xudihuxato/edit?html,css,output

Comment: I'd just like to point out that the selector `body, *` is redundant, because it's selecting both body... and everything(including body). So just do `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 720px) {

  .wrapper {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .box {
    flex-basis: 34%;
    background-color: blue;
  }

}
```

In your primary code you have the flex items set to `flex: 1`. This is the shorthand equivalent to:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 0`

Essentially, this takes the entire space on the row and divides it up equally among the four items.

To make the items break into a 2x2 grid, set the following rules in the media query:

1. Allow the items to wrap with `flex-wrap: wrap`. The default is `nowrap`.
2. Set the `flex-basis` to 50%, so only two items can fit on each row.

   If you want to make space for borders, padding and/or margins, set the `flex-basis` to 34% (or something like that).

   With `flex-grow: 1` defined in the main rule, there's no need for `flex-basis` to be 50%, which may result in one item per row due to the borders, padding or margins.

   Since `flex-grow` will consume free space on the row, `flex-basis` only needs to be large enough to enforce a wrap.

   In this case, with `flex-basis: 34%`, there's plenty of space for the margins, but not enough space for a third item on each line.

Comment: what is flex-basis 34%